# How do I rollback changes to both Stripe API and my MongoDB server at the same time in the same transaction? Or is it even possible?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, transactions, stripe-payments

I have the following code when I register users in my NodeJS application:

```
// BEGIN TRANSACTION

const new_customer = await stripe.customers.create({
  name: req.body.name,
  email: req.body.email,
});

const new_coupon = await stripe.promotionCodes.create({
  coupon: 'New-user-discount',
  customer: new_customer.id,
  code: "NEWUSER10",
  expires_at: new Date(Date.now() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), // expires in 24 hours
  max_redemptions: 1,
});

const new_user = await User.create({
  name: req.body.name,
  email: req.body.email,
  pword: hash(req.body.pword),
  stripe_customer_id: new_customer.id,
});

// END TRANSACTION
```

Two of the actions are doing things on my stripe account and the last one is doing thing on my database. However, if one of them were to fail, I don't want (for example) a stripe customer to be  registered without a user also being added to my database. I understand this is what transaction roll backs are for, but how can I implement this in my scenario using NodeJS??

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the above in a try catch. If creating the Stripe customer fails, then there's nothing to roll back as that's the first operation. If creating a coupon fails, how you handle that in the catch block is up to you (you could allow the user to retry, you could [delete the customer created in Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/delete), etc.). If creating the user in your database fails, then you could [delete the customer in Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/delete) in the catch block and [mark the promo code as inactive](https://stripe.com/docs/api/promotion_codes/update#update_promotion_code-active). It doesn't look like there's a way to delete a promo code.